# How to remove downloaded speech language in wp 8.1?

Tags: lumia, 8.1

I downloaded English U.S. Speech recognition (52MB) for Cortana, got bored of it and now I want to remove the speech language to free space.

I removed the language and changed region back, but speech is still there.

Can it be removed?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be a way to remove unused speech packs from the phone, *without a full reset of the phone*.

When you tap and hold on a particular language, no options appear to remove it.

Storage Sense also has no options to remove unused speech packs.

Comment: This definitely removes language packs, but not "speech packs" as used by Cortana for text-to-speech.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the language pack you want to remove might be the primary language at this time. Move the language to remove to the second position & then long tap to remove.

Means:
- Go to Settings>Language
- Move the language to remove to second place by Long tap > "move.." option
- Then long tap to remove the pack.

I tried this in "Denim" update. Not sure if this works in previous updates.